# JPAContainer with maven?

Tags: java, maven, jpa, vaadin, vaadin7

I've a problem with maven when add dependecy to JPAContainer-addon. The problem is thats returns a exception.

```
//archetype
mvn archetype:generate 
    -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin 
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application 
    -DarchetypeVersion=7.1.12 
    -DgroupId=br.ind.ibg
    -DartifactId=ibg_curriculuns_2
    -Dversion=1.0 
    -Dpackaging=war


//exception


 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [br.ind.ibg.MyVaadinUI$Servlet] in context with path [/ibg_curriculuns_2] threw exception [com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(Ljava/util/EventObject;Lcom/vaadin/server/ErrorHandler;)V] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(Ljava/util/EventObject;Lcom/vaadin/server/ErrorHandler;)V
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.onVaadinSessionStarted(VaadinService.java:783)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.createAndRegisterSession(VaadinService.java:740)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.doFindOrCreateVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:696)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.findOrCreateVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:637)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.findVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:501)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1376)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Which version of the jpacontainer did you specify in the pom file?

Comment: @AndréSchild, <version>1.2.0</version>

Comment: For vaadin 7.1 use jpacontainer 3.1 (3.1.1 at the moment) see https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-jpacontainer:vaadin